# How to create an Rascal AST from file

Tags: java, rascal

I've found the documentation on the Rascal site:
http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/lang/java/m3/AST/createAstFromFile/createAstFromFile.html
But I honestly have no idea how to apply this. Can someone give me an example of how to apply this in code?
I've tried some things, but either get missing modifier "java" or undeclared variables errors, which don't help me at all.

I'm currently stuck at:

```
ast = createAstFromFile(l,true,"1.8");
```

Two additional questions: what does "Declaration" add here? And what does the collectBindings boolean mean in this context?
(the documentation is not that clear related to this part of Rascal)

Additional information:

```
rascal>import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;
ok
rascal>createM3FromEclipseFile(|project://smallsql/src/smallsql/tools/CommandLine.java|);
|plugin://rascal_eclipse/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/lang/java/jdt/Project.rsc|(276,127,<11,0>,<12,47>): IO("**smallsql does not exist**")
        at somewhere plugin://rascal_eclipse/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/lang/java/jdt/Project.rsc|(276,127,<11,0>,<12,47>))
        at classPathForProject(|plugin://rascal_eclipse/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/lang/java/jdt/m3/Core.rsc|(1776,2,<54,55>,<54,57>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,82,<1,0>,<1,82>))


rascal>projects();
set[loc]: {
  |project://smallsql|,
  |project://MetricsTest|,
  |project://Analysis|,
  |project://hsqldb|
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar luck, but found the following workaround:

```
import lang::java::jdt::m3::AST;
createAstsFromEclipseProject(|project://myProject|,true)
```

This will give you all the asts for the project and you can select the one you need from that.

The issue is around compiler parameters (classpath etc). When given a project, the function can derive meta information from the project configuration which makes it work correctly.

- collectBindings means the files are not just parsed but also name binding and type binding is executed. This is useful but it takes more time.
- `Declaration` is just the general type of things that declare something.

Comment: Heads up: This method currently does not exist in Rascal anymore. The Rascal documentation is severely outdated, including deleted methods such as  `getMethodASTEclipse`. These things have been on the issue tracker for almost 4 years now and updating the documentation seems to have been abandoned.

Comment: Agreed we are short on contributions to the docs. Hard to find time, but in the meantime stackoverfkow can help. The function mentioned here is still there: in this module lang::java::jdt::m3::AST

Comment: You can follow our redocumentation progress here at http://docs.rascal-mpl.org which comes out of the CI . In the last few weeks many issues have been resolved by linking the docs with another Rascal runtime. Now we're working on splitting the docs per library module and reintegrating that nicely. It's a slow process due to other priorities.

Comment: That's annoying indeed. I didn't realize it did that still. Thanks for the ping! If this is bothering many people it should be a priority.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't. My apologies.

Comment: No problem. We appreciate your feedback. Keep it coming.